# Having problem with java methods as it is giving me 2 time the answer

Tags: java

Write a program that asks a user the radius of a circle, and calculates and displays the area. The program should only accept non-zero positive values for the radius and display an error message if the user tries to input a zero or negative value. The main method should be used to take the user input and pass it to the method circleArea for area
calculation.

The method circleArea should return the area which is then displayed from
method main via a print statement.

working:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {

public static double circleArea (double radius,double area,double pi) {

    area=pi*radius*radius;

    if(radius<=0) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("The area: "+area);
    }

    return area;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int r;
    final double p=3.142d;
    double ac = 0;


    System.out.println("Enter radius: ");
    r=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("area: " +circleArea(r,p,ac));


    }
    }
```

The output is giving me 2 time the area of the circle as below:
Enter radius: 
5
The area: 78.55
area: 78.55

Comment: No, it doesn't. You once print your result within the method, then you print it in your main method, where you print the returned value of your method

Comment: It prints 2 times because in your code you've written 2 output statements: `System.out.println("The area: "+area);` and `System.out.println("area: " +circleArea(r,p,ac));`

Comment: Your else part statement is printing the area and the way you have called the method itself is in print statement.

Comment: You have your arguments in the wrong order: `(double radius,double area,double pi)` vs. `(r,p,ac)`. I am surprised your code outputs 78.55, since `ac` is 0 and you're passing that as the value for `pi`.

Comment: but how can i print it once?

Comment: "but how can i print it once?" - Remove one of the print statements. Wasn't that obvious?

Answer (score 2):

It prints the result twice because once you print inside circleArea() method and then you print it once again in your main() method. If you remove one of these calls it should work fine

Comment: You are basically just repeating what both comments already said

Comment: @Stultuske: that's probably okay, because that should have been an answer. It literally answers the question.

Comment: @Stultuske but at least he gave an answer.